# Filter data frame based on frequency of a value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've reviewed many questions similar to mine, but I haven't yet found a clear solution for what I'm looking for (I'd be happy if you link to an answer if this is a duplicate or such question has been already answered).

I have a data frame like the following:

```
col_0 | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
---------------------------------------------
  0.2     1       1       1       1       1
  0.3    0.4      1       1       1       1
  0.1     1      0.3      1       1       1
```

I simply want to filter out/exclude those rows in which frequency of `1` is more than a threshold (generally a condition based frequency/count), let's say `4` here. As a result, I want a data frame like the following in my output:

```
col_0 | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
---------------------------------------------
  0.3    0.4      1       1       1       1
  0.1     1      0.3      1       1       1
```

So my key question is: how can we exclude rows in a data frame based on frequency/count of a specific value in them. And, ideally I want to specify a range of columns in a row, for example frequency of a value from column index 0 to 4 (not based on column name,) which I think this latter is not that challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df.loc[(df==1).sum(axis=1).between(0,4),:]
```

Comment: I don't think this is syntactically correct:`Unresolved attribute reference 'sum' for class 'bool' `

Comment: Why use `between` instead of `le`?

Comment: @Pedram it is syntactically correct, I've tested it on my end. You didn't give a [mcve] and that issue is something external to what you've listed in the problem

Comment: @roganjosh, OP wanted between a range so `between` is more general I guess?

Comment: Fair enough :) @Pedram `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0.2, 1, 1],'b': [1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],'c': [1, 1, 0.5, 0.6]})` is not a huge effort, for example, to have included in your question, for which this approach does work. If you don't give us the tools to build a representative DF, don't be surprised if the answers aren't plug-and-play

Comment: @thushv89 regardless of syntax, just to make sure I understand your code, in which part of the code you check the frequency?

Comment: @Pedram, that'll be `sum()`. So basically, we are first creating a filter (e.g. `(df == 1)` and then doing sum over axis=1, which gives the frequency of value 1 over columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[df.eq(1).sum(axis=1).le(4)]

   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5
1    0.3    0.4    1.0      1      1      1
2    0.1    1.0    0.3      1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest way, but maybe easy to see what is happening:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col_0' : [ 0.2, 0.3, 0.1], 
'col_1' : [ 1, 0.4, 1], 
'col_2' : [ 1, 1, 0.3], 
'col_3' : [ 1, 1, 1], 
'col_4' : [ 1, 1, 1], 
'col_5' : [ 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
def apply_freq_filter(df, value, frequency, col_start, col_end):
    f = df.iloc[:,col_start:col_end+1].apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)
    f = f[value] <= frequency
    return df[f]

df = apply_freq_filter(df, 1, 4, 0, 5)
print(df)
```

Comment: I'd argue that this is _far_ less readable than the two existing answers

Comment: But I believe primarily because it provides more generality than the others. If you would include start column, end column, variable value and frequency into the other solutions it might become harder to read. But point taken!

Comment: I'm kinda sitting on the fence because I see the point of extensibility but I'm thinking that's orthogonal to the premise of fast data processing, which `apply` just throws in the bin. The other approaches could still be packaged into a function :)